# Sum of ExtraHours Last Month(30 days) and Last 31-60 days

Tags: mdx

To calculate last month i did  :

```
Sum([V_DIM_Time].[Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember)
```

But show me error on `Mdx` code and not save it 
and about 31-60 days I think to do something like this:

```
Sum(
  {[V_DIM_Time].[Calendar].[Month].Lag(60):[V_DIM_Time].[Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember)}
  , [Measures].[openExtraHours]
)
```

or better(I mean faster) if I did new view and this view will calculate this days?

Comment: I don't really understand exectly what the question is?

Comment: this `.[Month].Lag(60)` is lagging 60 _months_ rather than 60 days. Do you have a [Date] level?

Comment: oh... so i need use [days] not [month] . tnx i try it